Provide different java libraries to javax.tools.JavaCompiler classpath
I am trying to parse this code with a JDK17 javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler:
public class TestClass {
    void foo() {
      var x = java.nio.file.Path.of("SomePath").resolve("foo", "goo");
    }
  }

I get a JavaCompiler instance like this:
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
var diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
var fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
var javaFileObjects = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(List.of(file));
JavacTask task = (JavacTask) compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, opts, null, javaFileObjects);
var cus = task.parse();

Now, the JDK 17 does not have the resolve(String,String) method signature for the Path class, and so I get an unknown var type.
If I needed to resolve symbols for some junit annotations, for example, I would provide the "-classpath", "path/to/junit/junit.jar" to the compiler, and the symbol would be resolved. But with java 23 for instance, I only have the /path/to/jdk23/lib/jrt-fs.jar library, and passing this to the classpath does not solve the issue.
It seems that running on Java 17 I can only rely on symbols of the JDK17 classes.
Is there any way to provide different java libraries to this JavaCompiler?

I don’t understand your problem’s relationship to “junit annotations” but even when you manage to point the bootclasspath to the different version, the JDK 17 compiler will most likely refuse to read the class files of a newer version than it can understand.

A better explanation of what you are try to achieve would help, because it seems unreasonable to expect any older JDK to compile for a later version (unless you use ProcessBuilder to launch the newer compiler).

I do not need to compile higher versions of Java syntax, I only need the semantic information about a new method's signature in a higher java version. The relation with any other external dependency (e.g. Junit) is that is not present in the standard libraries, and I provide it through the classpath, so that the compiler knows that @Test is @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test, the same way I need the compiler to understand that java.lang.String has a new method String.java27Method() that was not present in the JDK that was used to start the process

You're not describing an equivalent issue as most likely your junit is JDK8 compatible and isn't introducing replacement class definitions.

JUnit 5 is compiled to target Java 8. That means it can be used as a dependency in any project built by Java 8 or greater. Both at run-time and compile-time, Java N cannot read class files compiled to target Java M > N. For instance, if JUnit 5 was compiled to target, say, Java 21, then you would not be able to use JUnit 5 as a dependency in a project being built with Java 17. Nothing changes regarding this limitation just because the class you're trying to depend on is embedded in a run-time image.

Note you could compile your JavaCompiler project with Java 17 but then run it with Java 22+ and it will be able to compile code using Path::resolve(String,String...).
